# how to detect parameter in url HTTPGET json android

Tags: android, json, url, parameters

My problem is how to read parameter `HTTPGET ANDROID` (e.g. `http://aaa.com?category=abc`) in PHP.

My PHP function detects value "abc" as blank, how can I read parameter value?

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending the `GET` values from your android phone.

Comment: Have you tried $_GET['category']?

Comment: setting for URL before read json see here: http://pastebin.com/Yg4vaHJV

Comment: for setting HTTP GET to get json see here : http://pastebin.com/VPUUwFs4

Comment: i have used $_GET/$_REQUEST, it cannot read parameter GET

Comment: pls post your php code. WE DO think that your are trying to get $_GET['abc'] instead of $_GET['categroy']

Comment: please follow my source code PHP : http://pastebin.com/kHXkmKxM and http://pastebin.com/UvKn6rdQ